# Strange crash in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I did not have this issue before. Every thing was working fine, but recently the **UITextField** in my every view controller crashes when I touch at it. It throws some exception like  `-[UITextField window]:` message sent to deallocated instance 0x11843f80. I have properly set up the IBOutlet and actions, delegate for the UITextField. Until recently I did not have this problem but with addition of new view controller this problem has come across all the view controller that I am using. When I run lldb command to trace the application, the trace log shows something like this,

```
thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x02fb3dee CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 206, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x02fb3dee CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 206
    frame #1: 0x02fb3cb2 CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    frame #2: 0x00f6c592 UIKit`-[UITextSelectionView textSelectionViewActivated:] + 117
    frame #3: 0x0195ea29 Foundation`__57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 40
    frame #4: 0x03018855 CoreFoundation`___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 85
    frame #5: 0x03018778 CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 1976
    frame #6: 0x018a319a Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
    frame #7: 0x018afb03 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 55
    frame #8: 0x00f6bcb3 UIKit`-[UITextSelectionView activate] + 83
    frame #9: 0x00d428bb UIKit`-[UIFieldEditor becomeFieldEditorForView:] + 1523
    frame #10: 0x00d2ff02 UIKit`-[UITextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 99
    frame #11: 0x00d6e093 UIKit`-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 351
    frame #12: 0x00f4d8fb UIKit`-[UITextInteractionAssistant setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 208
    frame #13: 0x00f4f5f8 UIKit`-[UITextInteractionAssistant oneFingerTap:] + 1989
    frame #14: 0x00f47e29 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 143
    frame #15: 0x00f47133 UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 379
    frame #16: 0x00f483bf UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 46
    frame #17: 0x00f4aa21 UIKit`___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0541 + 57
    frame #18: 0x00f4a97c UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerApplyBlocksToArray + 277
    frame #19: 0x00f433d7 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 1026
    frame #20: 0x00ca81a2 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1121
    frame #21: 0x00ca8532 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 93
    frame #22: 0x00c8edc4 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 464
    frame #23: 0x00c82634 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196
    frame #24: 0x03451ef5 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 1274
    frame #25: 0x03021195 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    frame #26: 0x02f85ff2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    frame #27: 0x02f848da CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2218
    frame #28: 0x02f83d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    frame #29: 0x02f83c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #30: 0x034507d8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 190
    frame #31: 0x0345088a GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 103
    frame #32: 0x00c80626 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1163
    frame #33: 0x000a99bd Introdex`main + 141 at main.m:15
    frame #34: 0x000029d5 Introdex`start + 53

  thread #2: tid = 0x2103, 0x95de79ae libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent + 10
    frame #0: 0x95de79ae libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent + 10
    frame #1: 0x033f6372 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 918
    frame #2: 0x033f4be1 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 53

  thread #4: tid = 0x2303, 0x95de691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #0: 0x95de691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x969fa13b libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock + 595
    frame #2: 0x070e475e WebCore`_WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 46
    frame #3: 0x070e4455 WebCore`WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 37
    frame #4: 0x0302199e CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    frame #5: 0x02fb8640 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 384
    frame #6: 0x02f84635 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1541
    frame #7: 0x02f83d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    frame #8: 0x02f83c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #9: 0x070e4420 WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 560
    frame #10: 0x969f4557 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #8: tid = 0x2703, 0x95de47d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x95de47d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x95de3cb0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x0302110a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
    frame #3: 0x02f845d5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1445
    frame #4: 0x02f83d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    frame #5: 0x02f83c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x0199ce30 Foundation`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 398
    frame #7: 0x018ae4d6 Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
    frame #8: 0x018ae447 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1258
    frame #9: 0x969f4557 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #9: tid = 0x2803, 0x95de6be6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
    frame #0: 0x95de6be6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
    frame #1: 0x02fb57cb CoreFoundation`__CFSocketManager + 939
    frame #2: 0x969f4557 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #10: tid = 0x2903, 0x95de47d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x95de47d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x95de3cb0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x0302110a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
    frame #3: 0x02f845d5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1445
    frame #4: 0x02f83d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    frame #5: 0x02f83c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x06df9f50 WebCore`WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 176
    frame #7: 0x086ce807 JavaScriptCore`WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 71
    frame #8: 0x969f4557 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #18: tid = 0x3103, 0x95de47d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x95de47d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x95de3cb0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x0302110a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
    frame #3: 0x02f845d5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1445
    frame #4: 0x02f83d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    frame #5: 0x02f83c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x018e240f Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
    frame #7: 0x018e22d3 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
    frame #8: 0x0012853f Introdex`+[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] + 111 at AFURLConnectionOperation.m:156
    frame #9: 0x018ae4d6 Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
    frame #10: 0x018ae447 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1258
    frame #11: 0x969f4557 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #21: tid = 0x3403, 0x95de70ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x95de70ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x969f704c libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 45
    frame #2: 0x969f6e19 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 448
```

What might me the issue here. Please if anyone could help me, I would really be glad.

Comment: Have you tried doing 'clean' on your project? Is this a device och simulator crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Instruments for zombie. This will tell you what is really happening there.